# How to insert a new value in list map at the same time maintain same value for first index?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

What I'm trying to do is I have a list of folderTask like this:

```
List<FolderTask> folderTask = [];
folderTask = [FolderTask(name: name, task: [{task}];

// This is how the task value looks like:

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "note": note,
        "dueDate": dueDate,
        "reminderDate": reminderDate,
        "reminderTime": reminderTime,
        "repeat": repeat,
        "path": path,
        'isChecked': isChecked
      };
```

So task is a Map List. On my first page I did add folder name into folderTask list and on second page, I want to add the task list inside the folderTask list but it return error of RangeError.

Can someone help me? I'm using Flutter/dart lang to develop this app.

I want to add the task inside the list under the specific folder that has been created by the user on first page.

```
class FolderTask {
  String? name;
  List task;
  FolderTask({required this.name, required this.task});
  factory FolderTask.fromJson(json) {
    return FolderTask(name: json['name'], task: json['task']);
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {"name": name, "task": task};
}
```

Comment: could you include how FolderTask look like?

Comment: I already add the FolderTask model. Could you please check it?

Comment: Not sure why the comments got deleted. But to answer your latest question, the Data has value of [Instance of 'FolderTask']. Data = [Instance of 'FolderTask']